# angularjs: how to access the current element of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I need to be able to access the current element of ng-repeat inside a directive. See the jsfiddle for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/terebentina/TVEnN/

I am expecting a hash in the console (like {width: 100, height: 100}) but I am not really sure how to do that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the current element just be `scope.page` because you iterate over `page in pages`?

Comment: Thanks Philipp, if your comment would have been an answer I would've accepted it. For some reason I didn't know that scope would get that property.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that works ( and outputs what you are expecting).

http://jsfiddle.net/TVEnN/2/

Things to Note about `ng-repeat`:

1. `ng-repeat` always creates a NEW SCOPE for each element in the array / object.
2. The current element is available in this new scope as the name of the element defined in the `ng-repeat`. For ex: if you defined `ng-repeat = "page in pages"` then the current element is available in the scope as page. If you defined `ng-repeat = "(key,value) in object"` both `key` and `value` are available in this new scope.
3. The current position in the array is available as `$index`.
4. Since `ng-repeat` creates a new scope and all scopes inherit from their parent the `pages` in the above example is still available in this new scope, which means you could do stuff like `$scope.pages.length` if you need to.

Comment: Oh, for some reason I had no idea that page would be available through scope. Thank you very much.

Comment: What I am trying to do is a bit more complex - I need to render a svg container with raphaeljs and need to link the raphael paper object back to the {width, height} object so that later on can access it for further manipulation.

Comment: @DanCaragea Edited the answer for more explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice! Was just testing this. Implied from your #4 but good to point out specifically: a ng-repeat="inner in inners" inside a ng-repeat="outer in outers" would give your inner scope access to inner, inners, outer, outers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ganaraj's answer:

There's a pitfall when using filters. By using filters, e.g. to order items alphabetically, the `$index` resp. the `key` variable does no longer represent the actual position of the item in the items array, but its current position in the `ng-repeat`-block.

See [this link](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2014/11/10/angularjs-best-practices-avoid-using-ng-repeats-index/)